# Requesting feedback on database design

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I am building a database for a christmas tree growing operation.  I have put together, what I believe to be, a workable schema.  I am hoping to get some feedback from someone, and I have no one.  You are my only hope.

So, there are 3 growing plots, we will call them Orchards.  Each Orchard has rows & columns, and each row/column intersection can have zero or one trees, planted in it.  The rows/columns are numbers and letters, so row 3, column f, etc.  Each row/column intersection has a status (empty, in use). A tree can be different species (denoted by manually created GID {Genetic ID}), modified (have a different species grafted on), or moved to a different location. So a plant can have one or many locations, and a location can contain, through history, one or many trees, but only one at a time.

Here is a diagram I put together:

[image]

Comment: Do you really need TreeLocation?   Can a TreeId have more than one location at a time?

Comment: A tree can only be in one spot at a time, but it can move to a different location. So I was thinking for historical purposes, I would use the treelocation table.  Do you think it is unnecessary?

Answer (score 1):

> So I was thinking for historical purposes, I would use the
>   treelocation table. Do you think it is unnecessary?

No, but in that case you should have the information pertaining to the tree's location in the tree location table.   For instance "MovedYear".   If a tree moves multiple times, don't you want to keep the Year of each Move, instead of just one MovedYear for each tree?

It's fine to have a history table the way you do, but right now, if TreeId 1 has been in 3 different locations, how could you query your database to see which location it's in NOW?  All you'll see is:

```
TreeId LocationId
1      1
1      2
1      3
```

You won't know in what order the moves took place.  (Unless you have some business rule that says trees can only move from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3, and never follow any other order).

The usual way to solve this is to have a StartDate and EndDate in the history table.

Comment: Sounds good, I will likely keep the table, move the 'MovedYear' field and  and add the start/end date fields.  Hows the rest look?

Comment: I don't see any other obvious problems.   : )

Answer (score 0):

It seams

> A plant can have one or many locations

No, a plant have **a** location but it can move.
To gain this we need to

- Have location foreign key(FK) inside Tree table, showing current tree location.
- This FK needs to be mandatory (exposing have **a**)
- To prevent multiple trees having the same location we need to have a unique key constraint on this FK column.

A plant can move, so to trace a plants location history

- We will need a plant-location-history table

> Each row/column intersection has a status (empty, in use)

So the intersections status can have predefined limited values.

- Do we need a `LocationStatus` table? 
  I don't think so. status can be a static field inside locatin table with a check constraint of (1= empty, 2= in-use, 3= ETC)

[image]